# Conditional .htaccess block depending on url string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I write the following condition in my .htaccess file working with Apache 2.2.22?

- if my url contains the string "get-link", do not apply PHP compression `php_value output_handler ob_gzhandler` else apply

I didn't find anything on the web except rewrite conditions.

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: @anubhava : Apache version is 2.2.22. Do you have an idea?

Comment: It would have been very easy with Apache 2.3 or later where it has introduced `<if>` directive. It might still be possible but solution might be hackish.